# how does chrome browser's address bar autocomplete work

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, chromium, search-engine

I am implementing a pseudo-search engine that I will make as my default search engine on chrome and which will do some housekeeping before redirecting to google or something else.

I am interested in what data/request does the browser make to current search engine to make the "autocomplete" functionality work? The setting in the browser says - "Sends some cookies and searches from the address bar and search box to your default search engine"...
Which cookies and to what endpoint?

Any pointers?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237414/add-suggestion-url-for-custom-search-engine-in-chrome